# How do I add take a string of HTML and make it the child of some node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to do something like this:

Starting dom:

```
<div class="example"></div>

...

$('.example').somejqueryfunction('<span>Hello There</span>');

...

<div class="example">
    <span>Hello There</span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function:

```
$('.example').append('<span>Hello There</span>');
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for `jQuery.fn.html(string)`.

This makes your example look like this:

```
$('.example').html('<span>Hello There</span>');
```

This will replace the current html inside of the selected element. It should be noted that it only works on the first item of a match.

You can also use it as a getter by passing no parameters, though it again only works on the first item of a match.

[More information from the jQuery website.](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 2):

Use append() or prepend(). This will insert the given element at top or bottom of the target element.

Answer (score 2):

The append() function will add an HTML snippet (text, HTML elements) to the target element.

So for example,
$('.example').append('Hello There') would achieve the results you're looking for.

If you're looking to overwrite the entire contents within the element, the html() function will do that.

- append(): http://api.jquery.com/append/
- html(): http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for jquery append function.

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 1):

Many ways, depending on what you want to accomplish:

```
$('<span>').appendTo('div');
$('<span>').prependTo('div');
$('div').append('<span>');
$('div').prepend('<span>');
$('div').html('<span>');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ - Insert as first child

http://api.jquery.com/append/ - Insert as last child

http://api.jquery.com/html/ - Insert an replace entire content